# Auto index whole website with javascript library

Tags: javascript, algolia

How to auto index whole website using [Algolia javascript library](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js) ?
My front-end is made of django (and I would use django library), but I'm not using models, only **urls.py** file to get template files and show them. There is no database to import pages from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a crawler.

Algolia has been developing one for `DocSearch`. The service is targeted towards documentation websites.

However, the code is open-source, so you can run it on your own. [Here is the link to the crawler repository](https://github.com/algolia/docsearch-scraper).

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thank you very much.